# R: tune.svm return same performance for every combination of parameter

Tags: r, svm, libsvm

I have a dataset with 22 subjects and ~20000 features. I want to train a supporting vector regression nu model with linear kernel. In order to chose the best parameter for the model I am using the tune function in the package e1071 with the following call

```
Out = tune(svm,DependentVariable~.,data=Data,kernel="linear", ranges=list(cost=10^(-1:2), nu=seq(.1,1,.1))).
```

The output of this command is, as expected, the error and dispersion for each combination of the parameters, but the problem is that I get exactly the same error and dispersion for each combination.

This is very strange, especially considering that I am exploring the entire possible parameter space for nu.

What is possibly going wrong ?

Comment: Did you inspect a single model? Or you may compare just two of the resulting models? As you have way more variables than observation, my first guess would be that (independent of the given tuning parameters) each model just finds a "very bad" solution.

Comment: I think you may be right.
I have tested one model with C = 1 and nu = 0.1, and one model with C = 100 and nu = 0.5 (L-O-O CV). Both gave very bad solutions that correlate almost perfectly with each other.
I guess I will have to try some form of feature reduction.